# how to aggregate in pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
   code     date         tank      nozzle       qty      amount
   123      2018-01-01   1         1            100      0
   123      2018-01-01   1         2            0        50
   123      2018-01-01   1         2            0        50
   123      2018-01-01   1         2            100      0 
   123      2018-01-02   1         1            0        70
   123      2018-01-02   1         1            0        50
   123      2018-01-02   1         2            100      0
```

My desired dataframe is

```
code   date       tank     nozzle_1_qty   nozzle_2_qty  nozzle_1_amount   nozzle_2_amount
123   2018-01-01  1        100             100          0                 100
123   2018-01-02  1        0               100          120               0
```

I am doing following in pandas..

```
df= (df.pivot_table(index=['date', 'tank'], columns='nozzle',
                     values=['qty','amount']).add_prefix('nozzle_')
         .reset_index()
      )
```

But,this does not give me my desired output.

Comment: Please explain what do you want to do with your dataframe, it's not clear from your "desired dataframe".

Comment: Why does your expected output have 4 rows? There's only 2 unique combinations of `(code, date, tank)` in your input

Comment: I think here is not clear why first 4 rows of sample data with same `date` and `tank` are splitted to 2 final rows in desired output. Because there is same unique combination, so get one row in output.

Comment: @jezrael Sorry its bymistake, i have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default aggregation function in [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) is `np.mean`, so is necessary change it to `sum` and then flatten `MultiIndex` in list comprehension:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['code','date', 'tank'], 
                    columns='nozzle', 
                    values=['qty','amount'], aggfunc='sum')
#python 3.6+
df.columns = [f'nozzle_{b}_{a}' for a, b in df.columns]
#python bellow
#df.columns = ['nozzle_{}_{}'.format(b,a) for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   code        date  tank  nozzle_1_amount  nozzle_2_amount  nozzle_1_qty  \
0   123  2018-01-01     1                0              100           100   
1   123  2018-01-02     1              120                0             0   

   nozzle_2_qty  
0           100  
1           100
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use pivot_table much in pandas, but you can get your result using groupby and some reshaping.

```
df = df.groupby(['code', 'date', 'tank', 'nozzle']).sum().unstack()
```

The columns will be a MultiIndex that you maybe want to rename.

Comment: It is same like `df.pivot_table(index=['date', 'tank'], columns='nozzle',
                     values=['qty','amount'])`

Comment: @jezrael Not really. The layout is the same but the values are different. However, if you pass `aggfunc=np.sum` to `pivot_table`, then it's more similar. The default `aggfunc` is mean.